# Pandas : Cannot subtract dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have 2 simple data frames

df1

```
                                             colA    colB
0   e5b1b9fc-ade9-4501-a66b-ef2ecd57483e.d9967f258...  2ZWR52QYZ86H
1   8d127d82-cfa4-421f-9081-cf35132b8248.f0865b3b9...  61RPLMR5BFFT
2   005c8e84-98b4-402d-a24e-6a63edad0598.16b6f0f9f...  7L256IQTB1M1
3   d87f6dfd-1c55-4ce5-9b84-e80b6aa958d8.3f0901c7f...  3H9SLNATBJ01
4   cf89c9dd-004e-40e7-8120-3397ce5fd97e.f571bc175...  4Z8RT5VZNOQ8
5   9eebc606-e8d0-40e3-9ba5-6d3e1b77bc64.0dc42d528...  1DEOAHZL2JFC
6   7112aef1-5fa0-4459-aa1b-15cba2f96ec5.6a9ecb28d...  2CIISYGAAV69
7   e30d901c-34e6-4974-9b9e-1fe206ed6fca.701f1358e...  2NLLJ70RXKW2
8   13677989-8979-4422-a471-7fda22ea4f6d.e00051e45...  6P60G721DVHK
```

df2

```
0   e5b1b9fc-ade9-4501-a66b-ef2ecd57483e.d9967f258...  2ZWR52QYZ86H
1   8d127d82-cfa4-421f-9081-cf35132b8248.f0865b3b9...  61RPLMR5BFFT
2   005c8e84-98b4-402d-a24e-6a63edad0598.16b6f0f9f...  7L256IQTB1M1
3   d87f6dfd-1c55-4ce5-9b84-e80b6aa958d8.3f0901c7f...  3H9SLNATBJ01
4   cf89c9dd-004e-40e7-8120-3397ce5fd97e.f571bc175...  4Z8RT5VZNOQ8
```

now, i want to isolate the rows in df1, that are not in df2

so i tried

```
df1.subtract(df2)
```

but i get

```
result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(axis=1)]

Comment: that operation just gives me the df1

Comment: It should work. I just tested it. Do both of your data frames have the same column names? Also, the reason .subtract() doesn't work here is that the columns have both integers and letters, hence the str data type.

Comment: this worked for me
`concat_df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=False)`

Comment: Using pd.concat() and dropping duplicates is not correct in all cases if you want to get rows in df1 that are not in df2. That code would give you the expected result only if df2 doesn't have unique rows (df2 only has duplicates value of df1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` to get the rows in `df1` that are not in `df2`.

Using `indicator` parameter to check which rows are found in both data frames, only in the left data frame, or only in the right data frame.

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on=['colA', 'colB'], how='outer', indicator=True)
result_df = merged_df.loc[merged_df['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

Example output:

|  | colA | colB | _merge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 9eebc606-e8d0-40e3-9ba5-6d3e1b77bc64.0dc42d528 | 1DEOAHZL2JFC | left_only |
| 6 | 7112aef1-5fa0-4459-aa1b-15cba2f96ec5.6a9ecb28d | 2CIISYGAAV69 | left_only |
| 7 | e30d901c-34e6-4974-9b9e-1fe206ed6fca.701f1358e | 2NLLJ70RXKW2 | left_only |
| 8 | 13677989-8979-4422-a471-7fda22ea4f6d.e00051e45 | 6P60G721DVHK | left_only |

---

About your comment:

> this worked for me `concat_df = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=False)`

That option is only valid if df2 doesn't have rows that aren't in df1 (All rows in df2 are in df1). If both df1 and df2 have unique rows, using pd.concat() and dropping duplicates won't only isolate the rows in `df1` that are not in `df2` as you requested in your question, you would have all rows unique in df2 too